# HMM, reverse engineering the transition matrix

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, hidden-markov-models

I fitted a 2-states-HMM model last week, and generate a bunch of 1s and 0s, but I forgot to store its parameters (transition matrix). Now, I only got these 1s and 0s, how do I backward/reverse-engineering to estimates these transition matrix?

**Things that I have**:

1. the input data
2. the outputed 0s and 1s from a fitted 2-states-HMM

**What I want**:

1. The transition matrix of the two-states HMM model.

---

---

Please see the exact input and output data here:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N-PKaeHMVI4S1VU7fgcgDqRT5L3h8R0L?usp=sharing

And go to the bottom which it says `Input_data` and `Output_data`

Comment: Is the transition matrix graph kown?

Comment: I am trying to figure out the transition matrix of the two states HMM model

Comment: Is the output a generated ongoing sequence? Or is it restarting after a certain length? (Prior may be relevant then)

Comment: A single on-going sequence.

Comment: Can you make the input-output data available?

Comment: Yes, please see this link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1N-PKaeHMVI4S1VU7fgcgDqRT5L3h8R0L?usp=sharing

Comment: And go to the bottom which it says `Input_data` and `Output_data`

Comment: could you remind me, how exactly does input data come into a picture? So you have a Markov Chain with two states, and you have a noisy observation of a state, right?

Comment: Good question, I have the input data which is a numerical sequence, and I am trying to fit a HMM onto this numerical sequence, and I am trying to determine whether the sequence is of state 1 or state 0

Comment: I guess then you don't need the input data to get the lost HMM. You can just generate data using that HMM and fit to it